# In SQL Server, how can I change a column values depending on whether it contains a certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing... I'm trying to fix some data. Here goes the explanation:

Say I have two tables.

- The first is a lookup table that is no longer in use.
- The second has one varchar(50) column that sometimes has product names and
  sometimes has product ids from the old lookup table.

The idea is to convert all the PID values in the Product table into the product names.  Here's a pic i made up to help illustrate it:[image]

The lookup table is much larger, that's just an example.  So i'd guess it would be an update statement that would use the ProductsLookup.Name value if the Product value was found to be in the ProductsLookup.PID set?  How would this look in SQL?

Thanks much for the help,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `update` and `join`:

```
update p
    set product = pl.name
    from products p join
         productslookup pl
         on pl.pid = p.id;
```

A `left join` is not needed, because you only need to update the values that match in the lookup table.

I will caution you that performance might be an issue.  The problem is the types between the two tables -- presumably `pid` is a number not a string.  If so, you can create a computed column to change the type and an index on that column.

Comment: I think the product Name needs to relate to the product lookup ID on the left join. (are you missing you're left join?)  though using an inner you only update the records needing update...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - performance is not an issue here. It is obviously one time job. But I am wondering why do this as it will obviously create table with lot of duplicate items. Usually it is done other way, where you create links into table with names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put inner join with both these tables "ProductsLookup" and "Products" on PID and Product column. But Product column in "Products" table is varchar so you have to apply ISNUMERIC function on this column to make sure that join works fine. below is example

```
UPDATE
    P
SET
    P.Product=PL.Name
FROM
    Products P
    INNER JOIN ProductsLookup PL ON PL.PID=CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(P.Product)=1 THEN P.Product ELSE -1 END
```